# Fetch the column used for sorting in multiple orderby parameters postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, materialized-views

I am using the below query to create a materialized view schedule_state from the table schedule

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schedule_state AS (
    WITH schedule_latest_events AS (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() over (
                PARTITION BY key_id
                ORDER BY
                    header_event_timestamp DESC,
                    ktimestamp DESC,
                    raw_load_timestamp DESC,
                    update_timestamp DESC
            ) AS row_number
        FROM
            schedule
    )
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        schedule_latest_events
    WHERE
        row_number = 1
);
```

As I am using multiple columns to order by, is there any way I can figure out which column was used for sorting for the column with rank 1?

Also is it possible to get the max of four order by columns and assign the result to a column in the materialized view?
Thanks!

```
Table schedule

key_id,   header_event_timestamp,              ktimestamp,             raw_load_timestamp,         update_timestamp
k1,    2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000,  2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000, 2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000, 2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000
k1,    2023-12-22 08:50:37.530000,  2023-12-22 08:50:37.530000, 2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k2,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k2,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:45:03.060000, 2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k2,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-20 15:09:36.370000, 2023-12-21 02:52:37.557000, 2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000
K3,    2023-12-20 14:39:00.909832,  2023-12-20 14:39:00.909000, 2023-12-21 02:52:37.557000, 2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000
K3,    2023-12-20 14:39:00.909832,  2023-12-20 14:39:00.909000, 2023-12-21 02:55:37.557000, 2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000
k4,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k4,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k4,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000
k4,    2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000

MATERIALIZED VIEW schedule_state

key_id,   header_event_timestamp,              ktimestamp,             raw_load_timestamp,         update_timestamp         row_number
k1,    2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000,  2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000, 2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000, 2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000          1
k2,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:45:03.060000, 2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000          1
K3,    2023-12-20 14:39:00.909832,  2023-12-20 14:39:00.909000, 2023-12-21 02:55:37.557000, 2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000          1
k4,    2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000,  2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000, 2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000, 2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000          1
```

In the table

- For key_id k1 the first parameter header_event_timestamp was different so record with latest header_event_timestamp was assign rank 1.
- for key_id k2 the first parameter header_event_timestamp was same, so sorting was done based on the second parameter ktimestamp as that was different for key k2 and the record with the latest ktimestamp was assigned rank 1.
- for key_id k3 the first parameter header_event_timestamp and the second parameter ktimestamp were same, so sorting was done based on the third parameter raw_load_timestamp as that was different for key k3 and the record with the latest raw_load_timestamp was assigned rank 1.

Comment: Just a comment as I'm writting a bit in a rush but here it goes: would that work if you add another ORDER BY clause after your last filter (WHERE clause?)

Comment: Please can you update your question, possibly with data examples, to explain what you mean by “which column was used for sorting for the column with rank 1”? The 4 columns in your ORDER BY are the ones used to sort your data, so it’s not clear (to me) what you mean by a single column and why you think it applies to the row ranked 1 and not the others

Comment: "...which column was used for sorting for the column with rank 1?" -- All of them. That's how `ROW_NUMBER()` works.

Comment: Is seems you want GREATEST(header_event_timestamp,ktimestamp,raw_load_timestamp,update_timestamp) value, and also to use this in ORDER BY

Comment: Hi @NickW, I have modified the question and added an example

Comment: You should spend time to understand what @TheImpaler has written. The description added in last edit is wrong. Example: for `key_id` `k1`, the 2 records were sorted by `header_event_timestamp, ktimestamp, raw_load_timestamp, update_timestamp` (all `DESC`) and the record that ends with `ROW_NUMBER()` at 1 is the first, according to the defined [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Definition). If it was not done like so, what would be the behavior you desire for 3 records with the same `key_id`, but with only 2 having the same top `header_event_timestamp`?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to add records with `k4`, as an illustration of my previous comment. Could you please complete the question with what you expect for this case?

Comment: @Atmo, I spend time reading the postgres docs 
"When more than one expression is specified, the later values are used to sort rows that are equal according to the earlier values."

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-order.html

Comment: That is what lexicographic order means, yes.... how do you understand that sentence and how do you understand my first comment? + please edit your question (after "In the table") for the `k4` I added. The whole point of that case is that some but not all records share the same first field value, or the first 2 field values.

Comment: I get your point completely. For the key k4 if I am correct the final record was sorted based on the third column raw_load_timestamp after facing similar values for the previous 2 columns. My question was if it is possible to know that the final sorting for the rank 1 was associated because of that column.

Comment: So basically, you want to know on what column records with rank 1 (= the record that ends up selected) and rank 2 (= the closest record to the one selected) differ? And you do not care about the subsequent records?

Comment: I think that can solve my problem, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to determine the first column, among several defining an order, that discriminate between the first 2 records.

I have prepared the full example below, that I immediately comment with:

- For the sake of illustration, I added a `Schedule` CTE that you will need to remove yourself to get the real query. In that CTE:

  - There is 1 record with `key_id = ksingle`, to illustrate what happens when a record is alone.
  - Both records with `key_id = kequal` are the same, to illustrate what happens in case of a perfect tie.
- The query use 2 similar windows. I moved their definition in the `WINDOW` clause of the query in order to avoid repeats + have them next to each other for clarity.
  Regarding the window `w2`, as I defined it with `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, if you were to remove the final filter (`WHERE row_number = 1`), you would end up with a comparison of all records vs their respective next one. This is the effect of having a range that starts at the current row (row #2 is always the next row) rather than being e.g. `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` (for which, row #2 is the actual second one for the whole partition group).
- The below query implements 2 ways to tell you the discriminating column:

  - 4 columns returning booleans for the comparison of each of the columns used in the order vs the next value for the same column (window function `nth_value`, with parameter `2`).
  - An array constructed from the same booleans as above, for which the `array_position` is applied, which returns the first occurrence of `false`.

```sql
WITH Schedule(key_id, header_event_timestamp, ktimestamp, raw_load_timestamp, update_timestamp) AS ( VALUES
('ksingle', '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000', '2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000', '2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000'),
('kequal',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000', '2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000', '2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000'),
('kequal',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000', '2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000', '2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000'),
('k1',      '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000',  '2023-12-22 08:50:59.930000', '2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000', '2023-12-22 08:50:58.100000'),
('k1',      '2023-12-22 08:50:37.530000',  '2023-12-22 08:50:37.530000', '2023-12-22 08:52:36.960000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k2',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000', '2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k2',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 06:45:03.060000', '2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k2',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-20 15:09:36.370000', '2023-12-21 02:52:37.557000', '2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000'),
('k3',      '2023-12-20 14:39:00.909832',  '2023-12-20 14:39:00.909000', '2023-12-21 02:52:37.557000', '2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000'),
('k3',      '2023-12-20 14:39:00.909832',  '2023-12-20 14:39:00.909000', '2023-12-21 02:55:37.557000', '2023-12-20 14:04:37.323000'),
('k4',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000', '2023-12-22 06:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k4',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000', '2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k4',      '2023-12-22 06:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000', '2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000'),
('k4',      '2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000',  '2023-12-22 05:41:03.080000', '2023-12-22 05:52:33.189000', '2023-12-22 06:41:02.483000')
), schedule_latest_events AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER()                         OVER w1 AS row_number,
           nth_value(header_event_timestamp, 2) OVER w2 AS next_header_event_timestamp,
           nth_value(ktimestamp            , 2) OVER w2 AS next_ktimestamp,
           nth_value(raw_load_timestamp    , 2) OVER w2 AS next_raw_load_timestamp,
           nth_value(update_timestamp      , 2) OVER w2 AS next_update_timestamp
    FROM Schedule
    WINDOW
    w1 AS (PARTITION BY key_id ORDER BY header_event_timestamp DESC, ktimestamp DESC, raw_load_timestamp DESC, update_timestamp DESC),
    w2 AS (PARTITION BY key_id ORDER BY header_event_timestamp DESC, ktimestamp DESC, raw_load_timestamp DESC, update_timestamp DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
)
SELECT *,
       header_event_timestamp = next_header_event_timestamp AS test_header_event_timestamp,
       ktimestamp             = next_ktimestamp             AS test_ktimestamp,
       raw_load_timestamp     = next_raw_load_timestamp     AS test_raw_load_timestamp,
       update_timestamp       = next_update_timestamp       AS test_update_timestamp,
       array_position(ARRAY[
           header_event_timestamp = next_header_event_timestamp,
           ktimestamp             = next_ktimestamp,
           raw_load_timestamp     = next_raw_load_timestamp,
           update_timestamp       = next_update_timestamp
       ], 'false') AS first_different_column
FROM schedule_latest_events
WHERE row_number = 1
```

Since I made the query to illustrate several ways to represent the result you want, there is some redundancy in what the above query will return to you. I let you remove the columns you do not want to keep.

---

EDIT: @MatBailie has shared a version of the above query that uses the `LEAD` window function instead of `NTH_VALUE` and, importantly, only 1 window. That is only a minor code change compared to the above, with no difference on the result.

Until I find a way to generalize the above query (as I explained in the comment my initial attempt was to see if I could do something with a call to `generate_series(2, ...)`) (there is no guarantee I ever will be able to find one), his version is **superior**.

Comment: Why not use LEAD and the same window frame?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBeZSqYt

Comment: Because what I originally attempted involved a `generate_series` as the 2nd parameter of `nth_value` (it is not possible to add `generate_series` directly in the window function but it is OK with a cross join) and see if I could generalize the result. The attempt failed but traces of it remain, indeed.... I agree having only 1 window is a better way though....